# How can I check Shiro permissions for list of elements?

Tags: java, grails, shiro

I have Hibernate request that returns me list of elements to display. I need to check is current user able to view each of returned element. I can do it something like this

```
for (Element e : elements) { 
    SecurityUtils.getSubject().hasPermission("element:view:" + e.id);   
}
```

but this code will generate x requests to database per each element. So the speed of check will be O(n).

How can I improve my solution? Is it possible to get speed O(1)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method called `isPermittedAll(String ...)` on Subject which will return `true` if the Subject has all the permissions.

See: http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html#isPermittedAll%28java.lang.String...%29

Although, to be honest I don't know how much more efficient it is in terms of db queries (if at all).

Comment: I need to filter elements. I think if user doesn't have access to 1 element `isPermittedAll` will return `false` for all elements

Answer (score 0):

shiro supports caching, you can use for this type actions if you this list construction a lot. 
http://shiro.apache.org/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, you probably want to do the following:

```
String[] permissions = new String[elements.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    permissions[i] =  "element:view:" + e.id;
}

boolean[] allowed = SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(permissions);

List<Element> allowedElements = new ArrayList<Element>();

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    //1:1 match on entries in allowed to elements
    if (allowed[i]) {
        allowedElements.add(elements[i]);
    }
}

//allowedElements now contains the set of elements the user is permitted to access
return allowedElements;
```

The Subject API method I used is here: [boolean[] isPermitted(String... permissions)](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html#isPermitted%28java.lang.String...%29)

The downside to this approach is that you effectively end up iterating over your list of elements twice.  However you end up saving due to the fact you don't have to make a database call per element.

One thing to note, your run-time may change depending on how your security [Realm](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html) is implemented.